# Select TOP 1 from the result set

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to retrieve the top 1 value of result set of query which is connected using Union

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
(
    SELECT paused_time as end_time
        FROM production_time
        WHERE created_time = curdate()
    UNION 
    SELECT resumed_time as end_time
        FROM pause_timer
        WHERE created_time = curdate()
    UNION
    SELECT end_time as end_time
        FROM timer_idle
        WHERE created_time = curdate()
) as end_time
ORDER BY end_time DESC
```

But could not get the expected result.

Comment: `TOP 1` in MySQL is more like `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 0, 1`

Comment: Does this really work:  `created_time = curdate()`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is no `TOP` keyword in MySQL as far as I am aware. What you require is `Limit`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT paused_time as end_time FROM production_time WHERE created_time = curdate()
    UNION 
    SELECT resumed_time as end_time FROM  pause_timer WHERE created_time = curdate()
    UNION
    SELECT end_time as end_time FROM  timer_idle WHERE created_time = curdate()
) as end_time
ORDER BY end_time DESC 
LIMIT 1
```